# Método não está a listar na tabela, Java

Tags: java

```
public List<Vincular_Materia> listarV() {
        List<Vincular_Materia> lista = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            String sql = "SELECT m.nome_completo, d.nome_disciplina FROM tb_matriculas m INNER JOIN tb_vincular_disciplina v ON m.id_matricula=v.cod_alunos JOIN tb_disciplinas d ON v.cod_disciplina=d.id "
                    + "ORDER BY m.nome_completo";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                Matriculas m = new Matriculas();
                Disciplinas d = new Disciplinas();
                Vincular_Materia vinculo=new Vincular_Materia();
               //m.setId(rs.getInt("m.id_matricula"));
                m.setNome_completo(rs.getString("m.nome_completo"));
          
                d.setNome_disciplina(rs.getString("d.nome_disciplina"));
                vinculo.setDisciplina(d);
       
                lista.add(vinculo);
            }
            return lista;
        } catch (SQLException erro) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao criar a listaMatricula" + erro);
        }
        return null;
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Você precisa melhorar a sua pergunta, quais tecnologias está utilizando? Der uma descrição melhor do que essa.

Answer (score -4):

amigo, a classe Matricula não está sendo adicionada á lista.apenas a classe Vincular_Materia.

Para corrigir esse problema, você deve criar uma nova instância de Vincular_Materia e adicioná-la à lista em vez de criar uma nova instância de Matriculas e Disciplinas. Além disso, o método "setNome_completo" não está definido na classe Matriculas. Para resolver isso, você deve criar o método "setNome_completo" na classe Matriculas.
tente esse codigo:

```
public List<Vinc_Materia> listarV() {
List<Vinc_Materia> lista = new ArrayList<>();
try
String sql = "SELECT m.nome_completo, d.nome_disciplina FROM tbmatriculas m "
            + "INNER JOIN tb_vincular_disciplina v ON m.id_matricula=v.cod_alunos "
            + "JOIN tb_disciplinas d ON v.cod_disciplina=d.id "
            + "ORDER BY m.nome_completo";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Vincular_Materia vinculo = new Vincular_Materia();
        Matriculas matricula = new Matriculas();
        Disciplinas disciplina = new Disciplinas();

        matricula.setNome_completo(rs.getString("m.nome_completo"));
        disciplina.setNome_disciplina(rs.getString("d.nome_disciplina"));

        vinculo.setDisciplina(disciplina);
        vinculo.setMatricula(matricula);
        lista.add(vinculo);
    }
    return lista;
} catch (SQLException erro) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "erro ao criar a listaMatricula" + erro);
}
return null;
```

}
Neste código corrigido, uma nova instância de Vincular_Materia é criada em vez de Matriculas e Disciplinas. O método "setNome_completo" não é mais necessário, pois ele já existe na classe Matriculas. A nova instância de Vincular_Materia é adicionada à lista, que será retornada ao final do método
tente e me diga se funcionou.